# How to create custom sidebar of your own beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, formatting, presentations

I am trying to create my own beamer theme and wish to create a right sidebar having the same hight as the slides. Unfortunately this is not the case.

```
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar right}{bg=lightgray, fg=black}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=1.8cm}

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{}
```

Do you have any idea of how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `sidebar` outer theme has a documented `height` option:

> `height=⟨dimension⟩` specifies the height of the frame title rectangle. **If it is set to 0pt, no frame title rectangle is created**. Instead, the frame title is inserted normally into the frame.

Thus, you can just provide a `0pt` value for this option:

```
\useoutertheme[right, height=0pt]{sidebar}
```